# How to assigned a css-next variable into another one?

Tags: css, postcss, cssnext

Can someone confirm me if this works :

in my `.css` file, I have:

```
--pink-1000: #5A003C;

--old-pink: var(--pink-1000);
```

Will `--old-pink` have `#5A003C` as value ?

I'm using :

```
"postcss-cssnext": "~3.0.2",
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try it? This seems like an easy thing to test.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because if OP can easily test what they are asking.

Comment: My bad, I forgot I could try in a sandbox x)
Please don't be rude, it's almost end of the week, my brain need rest ;)

Comment: I'm not being rude, it's just a simple matter that you could have easily tested this before posting on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really easy to test yourself:

```css
:root {
  --pink-1000: #5A003C;
  --old-pink: var(--pink-1000);
}

p {
  color: var(--old-pink)
}
```

```html
<p>Test</p>
```

If you have easy to answer questions, it is often better to first look at MDN or the CSS Spec. You will find answers more quickly there and StackOverflow requires you to at least try to come up with a solution yourself. Just so you know for next time :)

Links for custom properties ("css variables"):

- MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*
- Spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-variables-1/